# Heroku couldn't connect to my mongodb atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

[image: ,]

As you can see, heroku can't connect to my mongodb. I using mongodb atlas cluster and im pretty sure that my ip address in whitelist. Because i tried it in my local and it perfectly worked. How can i deal with this problem? 
Besides all this, I may not be sure what the real problem is...

Comment: Are you whitelisting all IP addresses (`0.0.0.0/0`) ? because heroku does not provide static outbound IP, you are likely to get a different IP randomly

Comment: No im not get a different IP. I checked my ip on google. Also, i tried `0.0.0.0/0` too but its not worked...

Comment: Your IP on google not the IP of your dyno, even the IP of your dyno you check from tools like `nslookup` could be different from your "outbound" IP. If you have tried `0.0.0.0/0` and it's still not working, it means you might have entered your credentials incorrectly

Comment: My credentials are correct because i tried it in local with atlas cluster so many times... I tried nslookup on my cmd by the way and its told me that


`DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

heroku still cant connect to my mongodb atlas cluster but console starting to me show that results (i wrote this on my code take a look at the screenshoot)

Comment: 1. How do you know it's not connected? it's seems like you started just started the app, the error is from the previous run. 2. Please include this information in the question instead. 3. I hope your credentials in the screenshot is fake, if not you should remove it and change the password